# Selective ping error

Tags: router, internet, dns, proxy, ping

As you see below some sites do load and ping successfully others has to be opened using proxy such as "filterbypass"

Would this be routing problem or the DNS resolver/ firewall behind "static.tedata.net"

Should I call My ISP or something?

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup
Default Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

> set type=soa
> cyberguard.com

Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
cyberguard.com
    primary name server = ns-a.mcafee.com
    responsible mail addr = hostmaster.mcafee.com
    serial  = 2013011600
    refresh = 43200 (12 hours)
    retry   = 7200 (2 hours)
    expire  = 1296000 (15 days)
    default TTL = 86400 (1 day)
> ns-a.mcafee.com

Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

mcafee.com
        primary name server = mname.mcafee.com
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.mcafee.com
        serial  = 2014120600
        refresh = 720 (12 mins)
        retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
        expire  = 1209600 (14 days)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

exit



C:\Windows\system32>ping www.computerworld.com

Pinging cw.cloud.techhive.com [107.23.88.120] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 107.23.88.120:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Windows\system32>ping 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Windows\system32>pathping www.computerworld.com

Tracing route to cw.cloud.techhive.com [107.23.88.120]

over a maximum of 30 hops:

  0  Alan-PC [192.168.1.2]

  1  192.168.1.1

  2  172.31.1.121

  3  172.22.22.225

  4     *     host-196.219.225.69-static.tedata.net [196.219.225.69]

  5  10.37.242.246

  6  pos3-0.palermo6.pal.seabone.net [195.22.197.249]

  7  xe-2-0-1.ashburn2.ash.seabone.net [195.22.206.4]

  8  amazon.ashburn2.ash.seabone.net [195.22.206.59]

  9  205.251.245.5

 10  205.251.245.47

 11     *        *        *

Computing statistics for 250 seconds...

            Source to Here   This Node/Link

Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address 0                                          

 Alan-PC [192.168.1.2]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  1    0ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.1.1
                                2/ 100 =  2%   |

 2  296ms     2/ 100 =  2%     0/ 100 =  0%  172.31.1.121
                                3/ 100 =  3%   |

  3  285ms     6/ 100 =  6%     1/ 100 =  1%  172.22.22.225
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  4  312ms     5/ 100 =  5%     0/ 100 =  0%  host-196.219.225.69-static.tedata.
net [196.219.225.69]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  5  306ms     6/ 100 =  6%     1/ 100 =  1%  10.37.242.246
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  6  310ms     9/ 100 =  9%     4/ 100 =  4%  pos3-0.palermo6.pal.seabone.net [1
95.22.197.249]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  7  411ms     5/ 100 =  5%     0/ 100 =  0%  xe-2-0-1.ashburn2.ash.seabone.net
[195.22.206.4]
                               95/ 100 = 95%   |

  8  ---     100/ 100 =100%     0/ 100 =  0%  amazon.ashburn2.ash.seabone.net [1
95.22.206.59]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  9  ---     100/ 100 =100%     0/ 100 =  0%  205.251.245.5
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

 10  ---     100/ 100 =100%     0/ 100 =  0%  205.251.245.47

Trace complete.


C:\Windows\system32>ping http://www.pof.com/
Ping request could not find host http://www.pof.com/. Please check the name and
try again.

C:\Windows\system32>ping www.pof.com

Pinging pof.com [199.182.216.166] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 199.182.216.166:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Windows\system32>pathping www.pof.com

Tracing route to pof.com [199.182.216.166]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  Alan-PC [192.168.1.2]

  1  192.168.1.1

  2     *     172.31.1.121

  3  172.22.22.225

  4  host-196.219.228.25-static.tedata.net [196.219.228.25]

  5  10.37.242.242

  6  so-1-0-0.lon12.ip4.gtt.net [141.136.98.33]

  7  xe-3-2-1.van10.ip4.gtt.net [141.136.108.34]

  8     *        *        *

Computing statistics for 175 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  0                                           Alan-PC [192.168.1.2]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  1    0ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.1.1
                                5/ 100 =  5%   |

  2  371ms     7/ 100 =  7%     2/ 100 =  2%  172.31.1.121
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  3  380ms    13/ 100 = 13%     8/ 100 =  8%  172.22.22.225
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  4  391ms     6/ 100 =  6%     1/ 100 =  1%  host-196.219.228.25-static.tedata.
net [196.219.228.25]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  5  389ms    10/ 100 = 10%     5/ 100 =  5%  10.37.242.242
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  6  446ms     5/ 100 =  5%     0/ 100 =  0%  so-1-0-0.lon12.ip4.gtt.net [141.13
6.98.33]
                               95/ 100 = 95%   |

  7  ---     100/ 100 =100%     0/ 100 =  0%  xe-3-2-1.van10.ip4.gtt.net [141.13
6.108.34]

Trace complete.

C:\Windows\system32>ping www.bgp4.as

Pinging www.bgp4.as [80.69.78.247] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 80.69.78.247:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Windows\system32>pathping www.bgp4.as

Tracing route to www.bgp4.as [80.69.78.247]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  Alan-PC [192.168.1.2]

  1  192.168.1.1

  2  172.31.1.121

  3  172.22.22.225

  4  host-196.219.225.69-static.tedata.net [196.219.225.69]

  5  10.37.241.13

  6  gig4-0-6.70-gsr04.ath.OTEGlobe.net [62.75.3.249]

  7     *        *        *

Computing statistics for 150 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  0                                           Alan-PC [192.168.1.2]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  1    0ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.1.1
                                1/ 100 =  1%   |

  2  344ms     6/ 100 =  6%     5/ 100 =  5%  172.31.1.121
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  3  350ms     3/ 100 =  3%     2/ 100 =  2%  172.22.22.225
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  4  356ms     4/ 100 =  4%     3/ 100 =  3%  host-196.219.225.69-static.tedata.
net [196.219.225.69]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  5  384ms     4/ 100 =  4%     3/ 100 =  3%  10.37.241.13
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |

  6  426ms     1/ 100 =  1%     0/ 100 =  0%  gig4-0-6.70-gsr04.ath.OTEGlobe.net
 [62.75.3.249]

Trace complete.

C:\Windows\system32>ping www.yahoo.com

Pinging fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com [46.228.47.115] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 46.228.47.115: bytes=32 time=516ms TTL=51
Reply from 46.228.47.115: bytes=32 time=515ms TTL=51
Reply from 46.228.47.115: bytes=32 time=305ms TTL=51
Reply from 46.228.47.115: bytes=32 time=554ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 46.228.47.115:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 305ms, Maximum = 554ms, Average = 472ms

C:\Windows\system32>

C:\Windows\system32>ping superuser.com

Pinging superuser.com [198.252.206.140] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 198.252.206.140: bytes=32 time=665ms TTL=50
Reply from 198.252.206.140: bytes=32 time=783ms TTL=50
Reply from 198.252.206.140: bytes=32 time=760ms TTL=50
Reply from 198.252.206.140: bytes=32 time=628ms TTL=50

Ping statistics for 198.252.206.140:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
```

### Minimum = 628ms, Maximum = 783ms, Average = 709ms

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>nslookup

Default Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

> set type=soa
>
> pof.com

Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com

Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
pof.com

```
    primary name server = pdns80.ultradns.com

    responsible mail addr = owen.pof.com

    serial  = 2013071719

    refresh = 86400 (1 day)

    retry   = 86400 (1 day)

    expire  = 86400 (1 day)

    default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)
```

> ping pdns80.ultradns.com

Server:  pdns80.ultradns.com

Addresses:  2001:502:f3ff::74

```
      156.154.64.80
```

*** pdns80.ultradns.com can't find ping: No response from server

> exit

C:\Windows\system32>ping pof.com

Pinging pof.com [199.182.216.166] with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.

Request timed out.

Request timed out.

Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 199.182.216.166:

```
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

C:\Windows\system32>pathping pof.com

Tracing route to pof.com [199.182.216.166]

over a maximum of 30 hops:

0  Alan-PC [192.168.1.2]

1  192.168.1.1

2  172.31.1.121

3  172.22.22.225

4  host-41.33.204.245.tedata.net [41.33.204.245]

5  10.37.11.129

6  so-1-0-0.lon12.ip4.gtt.net [141.136.98.33]

7  xe-3-2-1.van10.ip4.gtt.net [141.136.108.34]

8     *        *        *

Computing statistics for 175 seconds...

```
        Source to Here   This Node/Link
```

Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address

0                                           Alan-PC [192.168.1.2]

```
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
```

1    0ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.1.1

```
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
```

2   16ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  172.31.1.121

```
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
```

3   14ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  172.22.22.225

```
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
```

4   15ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  host-41.33.204.245.tedata.net [41.

33.204.245]

```
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
```

5   21ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  10.37.11.129

```
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
```

6   83ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  so-1-0-0.lon12.ip4.gtt.net [141.13

6.98.33]

```
                          100/ 100 =100%   |
```

7  ---     100/ 100 =100%     0/ 100 =  0%  xe-3-2-1.van10.ip4.gtt.net [141.13
6.108.34]

Trace complete.

C:\Windows\system32>pathping pdns80.ultradns.com

Tracing route to pdns80.ultradns.com [156.154.64.80]

over a maximum of 30 hops:

0  Alan-PC [192.168.1.2]

1  General failure.

Computing statistics for 25 seconds...

```
        Source to Here   This Node/Link
```

Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address

0                                           Alan-PC [192.168.1.2]

```
                          100/ 100 =100%   |
```

1  ---     100/ 100 =100%     0/ 100 =  0%  Alan-PC [0.0.0.0]

Trace complete.

C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Alan-PC

Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :

Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid

IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 5:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11b/g WLAN

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1A-73-E3-65-41

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : NVIDIA nForce 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1D-72-44-05-51

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred)

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, December 09, 2014 4:36:11 PM

Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, December 10, 2014 5:49:41 PM

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8

```
                                   8.8.4.4
```

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 7:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{27C010C7-DB92-4CDE-9448-20B429F20
407}

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-00-54-55-4E-01

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 14:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{53796AF4-2832-4971-9043-C67B81BF6
F59}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 15:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{4DE5AC89-1E2B-4646-9D94-C2D26FBAD
A8A}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
[image]

[image: MTR pof.com]

Comment: Many web sites blocked ping (e.g. www.computerworld.com) but works fine in browser.  Suggest use [psping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) to check web site connectivity.  psping www.computerworld.com:80

Comment: Who owns the machine with IP Address `172.31.1.121`? You are getting up to 5% packet loss between your router `192.168.1.1` and `172.31.1.121`

Comment: PsPing did not work on this Vista SP2. It terminate right-away.

Comment: This 172.31.1.121 should be first access point at ADSL subscription

Comment: Not sure why psping didn't work, the [web site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx) mentioned Vista or higher should work.  You can also check [Ping a Specific Port](http://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port) for more similar tools.

Comment: www.computerworld.com does load but the other two yet do not load.

Comment: checked for answer regarding PSping and Vista. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/psping-instantly-terminate-vista-sp2/283fc1e5-8707-4aae-ace6-d9d8c73975ae?tm=1418155053350

Comment: This link is from (http://anti-hacker-alliance.com/) the closest I could found to PSping:    https://www.dropbox.com/s/npxgnbu83xxwvhc/The%20Anti%20Hacker%20Alliance%20fights%20against%2041.69.217.151.pdf?dl=0